# Tomcat 8.5.27 compilation fails with error 'illegal start of type' for JSP pages when type inference was used

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I'm using tomcat 8.5.27 and upon compiling the JSP pages with tomcat 8.5.27, I'm getting a compile error stating "illegal start of type".

ERROR :

```
RESTProxy_jsp.java:30: illegal start of type
    [javac]     _jspx_imports_packages = new java.util.HashSet<>();
                                                               ^
```

However, if I change the tomcat to Tomcat 7.0.69, Build is observed to be SUCCESS and there is NO compile error reported.

Upon analyzing further, I observed that Tomcat 8.x compiles the JSP pages different to that of Tomcat 7.x and it adds the below set of code to the compiled version of JSP files which causes a compilation error eventually.

```
    private static final java.util.Set<java.lang.String> _jspx_imports_packages;

     private static final java.util.Set<java.lang.String> _jspx_imports_classes;

     static {
        _jspx_imports_packages = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        _jspx_imports_packages.add("javax.servlet");
        _jspx_imports_packages.add("javax.servlet.jsp");
        _jspx_imports_packages.add("javax.servlet.http");
        _jspx_imports_classes = new java.util.HashSet<>();
        _jspx_imports_classes.add("com.abc.studio.xyz.BackEndHandler");
  }
```

I'm using Java 1.7.0_80, Can any of you please advise why I'm getting this error though I'm using JDK 7 and we all know that Java 7 supports type inference.

Comment: Didn't you mean `new java.util.HashSet();`, without the diamond?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, No, it is with diamond (<>) only as shown in the auto generated code above. 
 In fact, the static block gets created by the tomcat 8.5.27 during the JSP compilation process and I didn't created those code snippets. 

This code gets created only with Tomcat 8.x and not with the earlier versions of tomcat !!

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca : Can you please advise on this compiler error ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca :  Do you have any idea  from where did the above static block {} gets added after compilation.  This would help me identify the problem .

Comment: No idea at all, sorry. I answered at first just because that syntax weirded me out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166405/discussion-between-raguram-and-federico-klez-culloca).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved after upgrading the **tools.jar** to Java 8.